# clear connection pool used by System.Net.WebClient

Tags: .net, system.net

Does anyone know how to clear the connection pool of System.Net.WebClient, or to force such a client to use a new connection for a request?

(likewise, if I could do the same with a HttpWebRequest that would be fine)

Comment: Can't you just set `KeepAlive` to `false`?

Comment: I didn't try this, but I assumed that would prevent the connection from being reused later but not prevent a connection being reused for that request (where keepalive was set to false).

Comment: Yeah, but if you set `KeepAlive` to false for all requests, then there should be no connection pooling. Anyway, why exactly do you want this behavior?

Comment: I was trying to isolate a bug, but that has been solved so at this point I don't need this.  Thanks for the help.